# Get documents with field that isn't a particular string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

I want to get the documents from MongoDB that **don't** have the field `"name":"John"` (just an example).

How can I do this?

For getting the documents that have the field `"name":"John"` I use:

```
db.col.find({"name":"John"})
```

I've already tried `...find(!{"name":"John"})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.col.find({"name":{$ne: "John"}})
```

should work, here are docs: [Mongo, Advanced Queries.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#AdvancedQueries-%24ne)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `$ne` selector like this:

```
db.col.find({"name":{$ne:"John"}})
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/ne/#_S_ne